# Mypy: Type of dict value doesn't change with assignment while type of variable does

Tags: python, mypy, python-typing

In the following example, why does the type of the variable `foo` change when it's value is set to an integer but the same doesn't occur for the type of `bar["foo"]`?

```py
import typing as tp

foo: tp.Union[float, int]
D = tp.TypedDict("D", {"foo": tp.Union[float, int]})

foo = 123.45
bar = D(foo=123.45)

reveal_type(foo)  # main.py:9: note: Revealed type is 'builtins.float'
reveal_type(bar["foo"])  # main.py:10: note: Revealed type is 'builtins.float'

foo = int(foo)
bar["foo"] = int(bar["foo"])

reveal_type(foo)  # main.py:15: note: Revealed type is 'builtins.int'
reveal_type(bar["foo"])  # main.py:16: note: Revealed type is 'builtins.float'
```

Answer (score 2):

This is due to some `mypy` features:

- **Type narrowing for `Union`.**

Any assignment after the initial declaration will narrow the type down

```
x: Union[int, float]
x = 1.1
reveal_type(x)  # Revealed type is 'builtins.float'
```

But `mypy` does not narrow down types in an assignment:

```
x: Union[int, float] = 1.1
reveal_type(x)  # Revealed type is 'Union[builtins.int, builtins.float]'
```

- **The so-called `promotion of types` by the `mypy`.**

For example, `int` is not a subtype of `float` in runtime, but the `mypy` considers it so. And wherever `float` is expected, an `int` can be passed (sometimes it may not be obvious), although it is not a subtype of it.

- **Simplifying of `Union` for class attributes**

```
class A:
    x: Union[bool, int, float]  

reveal_type(A.x)  # Revealed type is 'builtins.float'
```

This result is because `bool` is a subtype of `int` and `int` is promoted to `float` by the `mypy`.

In your example for `TypedDict`, there is a `Union` simplifying, like below

```
from typing import Union, TypedDict

D = TypedDict("D", {"x": Union[int, float]}) 
d: D
y: Union[int, float]

reveal_type(d["x"])  # Revealed type is 'builtins.float'
reveal_type(y)  # Revealed type is 'Union[builtins.int, builtins.float]'
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, I'll spend some time reviewing the concepts before I accept in case I have some follow up questions.